# Amazon S3 DELETE Request Successful but returns no confirmation?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am testing the S3 REST endpoints using Postman creating the DELETE request as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html).

The DELETE request returns a `204` (No Content) response with the following headers:

```
Content-Length →0
Date →Wed, 15 Aug 2018 21:11:38 GMT
x-amz-request-id →3458780640
```

The file before the command was present, after the request the file was deleted so I know the request is working. But theres nothing from the response to really confirm.

Can anyone explain why? I am planning to run this in an automated script so I need to be able to monitor whether files have been successfully deleted.

Comment: Why is the 204 response not sufficient? This HTTP status code means the request completed successfully.

Comment: 204 should be enough to tell you that your request was processed fine, but no response was necessary

Comment: @dmulter This will do in that case. The return status says 204 = No Content so I assumed it meant it hasn't found the file.

Comment: You'll also see 204 if the file was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html) they state:

> This implementation of the operation does not return response elements.

If versioning is enabled on the S3 bucket, they do however return some values in the response headers:

`x-amz-delete-marker` and `x-amz-version-id`

The delete marker is an indication that the object was deleted, and you can also use it to [un-delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/undelete-objects.html) that object.

Comment: But I don't get either of the headers you've listed in your answer.

Comment: @Imran you wouldn't get those unless the bucket has versioning enabled.